# Set a value if null inserted in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, insert, null

I have created a trigger, that will automatically set the first column values as subsequent factorial numbers. However, additionally, I would like to set the second column's value as the value of first incremented by 5, in case a null value is inserted. Here's what I try right now:

```
create or replace trigger test_tr
before insert on myT
for each row 
begin

IF :new.mNumb is null 
THEN       
    UPDATE myT
    SET mNumb = :new.tab_id + 5;
END IF;


SELECT fac(test_seq.NEXTVAL)
INTO   :new.tab_id
FROM   dual;


end;
```

But clearly I'm missing something, as nothing happens, the inserted null is still empty.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Also, why are you inserting factorial numbers? You'll only be able to add 83 rows based on the sequence before you start running into numeric overflows! In all likelihood, the issue is that :new.tab_id is null, and null + <any number> is still null.

Comment: It's not my personal goal to insert factorials, it's just a university exercise. And why would tab_id be null?

Comment: I don't know; you didn't mention your database version, your table structures or any sample data, so I made a guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not re-update the table in your trigger, update the row you're given directly:

```
...

IF :new.mNumb is null 
THEN       
    :new.mNumb = :new.tab_id + 5;
END IF;

...
```

Comment: Okay, that's a valid point. I did it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: does this work or not? why is this accepted if it didnt work?

Answer (score 1):

It all works as expected, using Emmanuel's suggestion to remove the update stmt, as far as I can tell. Here's the test case I used:

```
drop table test;

create table test (col1 number, col2 number);

create trigger test_trg
before insert on test
for each row 
begin

IF :new.col2 is null 
THEN       
    :new.col2 := :new.col1 + 5;
END IF;

:new.col1 := dbms_random.value;

end;
/

insert into test values (1, 1);

insert into test values (1, null);

insert into test values (null, null);

commit;

select * from test;
```

which produces the following output:

```
      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
.617580128          1
.030570358          6
.555066268
```

Maybe if you set :new.col1 before dealing with the null col2 scenario, that would work better for you? Doing that produces:

```
      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
.302670917          1
.024927489 5.02492749
.667568400 5.66756840
```